# git checkout -t shows modified files

Tags: git

```
$ git checkout -t origin/integrated
$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
src/me/unroll/scanner/moduletestset/apple.eml
```

What could be causing this?  Note this is immediately after a `git clone.`

Seems to have to do with CRLF issues.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but I wasn't able to make it happen...frustrating.

Comment: @EthanBrown - do you have any suggestion for what other information to post here without giving you access to my company's repo?  I don't know what the problem is so have no idea what information would be useful to help repro.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think of much.  You might want to include what your `core.autocrlf` and `core.whitespace` values are....

Comment: what't the output of `git diff`?

Answer (score 0):

you should try with `core.autocrlf` set to false.

The other thing is that you can just do

```
git checkout integrated
```